# How can I create new columns with filter on the current column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bucket my own category for the dataset I have. Currently, I have a column rating that is somehow continuous, I want to create a new column called category and its value will depend on the values from rating.
here are my codes:

```
st_df['Category'] = st_df['Rating'].map({(['Rating'] > 89): 4, (['Rating'] < 90): 3,
                                         (['Rating'] < 80): 2, (['Rating'] < 70): 1,
                                         (['Rating'] < 60): 0})
```

the error I have is: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].